# How can I call a custom function in tryton after record creation?

Tags: tryton

I need to perform a notification on a non tryton database after the creation of the record.

I see that it's possible to overwrite the create function.. but there is any better solutions to be sure to be after the commit of the database ?

I do in this way

> ```
> @classmethod
> def create(cls, values):
>     newObject = super(Inventory, cls).create(values)
>     newObject.notifieToMainServer()
> ```

regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call a function when the Transcation is commited by using the [atexit](https://docs.tryton.org/projects/server/en/latest/ref/transaction.html#trytond.transaction.Transaction.atexit) function of the tryton Transaction.

So your code will be something like:

```
from trytond.transaction import Transaction

@classmethod
def create(cls, values):
   records = super().create(values)
   Transaction.atexit(notifyToMainServer)
   return records
```

If you need to prevent the commit of the transaction when the notification can not be sent, you can use the Two-Phase commit protocol by [joining some datamangers on the Transaction](https://docs.tryton.org/projects/server/en/latest/ref/transaction.html?highlight=phase#trytond.transaction.Transaction.join). Tryton by default implements an [sendmail_transactional](https://hg.tryton.org/trytond/file/252ef79e6896/trytond/sendmail.py#l16) function which may be used as reference for implementing a DataManager to send your custom notifications.

Hope it helps!